# Seeing "fatal: Refusing to point HEAD outside of refs/" after every command I run in the terminal

Tags: fish

I haven't used the terminal in a few weeks, after running "Brew Upgrade" to upgrade/update all my packages, I started seeing "fatal: Refusing to point HEAD outside of refs/" after every command I run. I'm not that versed with the terminal or Git, so I have no idea what this means, please offer some suggestions/scenarios for why this may be happening.

Comment: `cat .git/HEAD` ?

Comment: when I run that it returns:

ref: refs/heads/master
fatal: Refusing to point HEAD outside of refs/

Comment: You have set up your shell (command line interpreter) to run some sort of Git command(s) on every command you run, and the commands you're having it run are wrong. We can't tell you *what* commands *you're* having *your* shell run because we do not have your computer. You are going to have to give us a lot more information about what you did to set this all up.

Comment: `.git/HEAD` is ok, the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: @torek i didn't set anything up, everything was working fine until I ran 'brew upgrade' in the terminal a few days again, I don't even know how to set up what you're referring to. How would you set up something like that? Maybe I could try to figure out the issue from that standpoint.

Comment: You did set something up - you replied to a comment below that says that yes, you are using the "fish" shell. I'm not familiar with that particular shell but it does not come with macOS.

Comment: Sure I installed the fish shell, but I didn't configure it to run any git commands. Per the github issue below, fish shell disabled '^', I don't know enough about terminals to set up scripts and whatnot, was just trying to get some assistance on this strange error

Answer (score 24):

I'll bet that you are using the `fish` shell, and upgraded to version 3.3.0 when you ran `brew upgrade`.

I'll also bet that you have a custom prompt running a command with error redirection using the circumflex diacritic (`^`). This is no longer a valid syntax :

> Redirection to standard error with the ^ character has been disabled by default. It can be turned back on using the stderr-nocaret feature flag, but will eventually be disabled completely ([#7105](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/7105)).

The solution is to replace all the `^` used for error redirection in your config with `2>`.

For example :

```sh
git symbolic-ref HEAD ^/dev/null
```

becomes

```sh
git symbolic-ref HEAD 2>/dev/null
```

---

All credit to [Njke](https://github.com/Njke) on [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/8105#issuecomment-875026707).

Comment: I am using fish shell and its on version 3.3.1 now, but when I ran the command you provided, it returned:

refs/heads/master
fatal: Refusing to point HEAD outside of refs/

And it still shows 'fatal: Refusing to point HEAD outside of refs/' after every command I run, no matter what the command is.

Comment: I ran `set -U fish_features no-stderr-nocaret` suggested by @faho on the [Github Issue](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/8105#issuecomment-873448774) you referenced and that seems to have rid the error. Thanks a bunch for your help!!

Comment: To complete the answer, on my config the responsible file was the prompt config
`~/.config/fish/functions/fish_prompt.fish`.

This file can be corrected by the following procedure:
running `fish_config`, checking the curent prompt used, and selecting it again (possibly after changing it to a random other prompt). This recreates the file with the new version updated by you package manager. I wonder why this file is a copy instaed of a softlink, but hey that is what it is.

Comment: Since I don't used a ^ in my fish config. I had to run fish_config and change my promt style to fix the error .. In case someone else runs into this