# Error getting triggered on every new prompt

Tags: macos, macos-big-sur, fish

After updating a bunch of utilities via brew, I upgraded `fish shell` from something close to 3.0 to 3.3.1. Now there's a series of so-far harmless, but highly distracting error messages appearing every time I hit `return` in Terminal.

```
$ ls
README.md         node_modules      package.json      static            tsconfig.json
mdsvex.config.cjs package-lock.json src               svelte.config.js  work.eqg
fatal: ambiguous argument '^/dev/null': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
fatal: bad revision '^/dev/null'
fatal: Refusing to point HEAD outside of refs/
fatal: No names found, cannot describe anything.
head: ^/dev/null: No such file or directory
$ echo Hi 
Hi 
fatal: ambiguous argument '^/dev/null': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
fatal: bad revision '^/dev/null'
fatal: Refusing to point HEAD outside of refs/
fatal: No names found, cannot describe anything.
head: ^/dev/null: No such file or directory
$ 
fatal: ambiguous argument '^/dev/null': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
fatal: bad revision '^/dev/null'
fatal: Refusing to point HEAD outside of refs/
fatal: No names found, cannot describe anything.
head: ^/dev/null: No such file or directory
$
```

*Note: I've simplified my prompt to just `$` because a lot of it doesn't copy/paste well. Fwiw, I'm using Bob the Fish, & here's a screenshot:*

[image: screenshot of above error message]

Anyway…any ideas for how to troubleshoot this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Seeing "fatal: Refusing to point HEAD outside of refs/" after every command I run in the terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68434304/seeing-fatal-refusing-to-point-head-outside-of-refs-after-every-command-i-ru)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`fish-shell/fish-shell` issue 8105](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/8105#issuecomment-875026707) mentions:

> If you encounter these errors in prompt after updating fish shell to 3.3.0:
>
> fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
> fatal: Refusing to point HEAD outside of refs/
>
> Then probably you have error redirection with caret (`^`) in your prompt.
> Replace it with `2>`.

It suggests:

> Doing a full `grep -r '\^[/&]' ~/.config/fish/` and fixing everything that comes up (that isn't already quoted)

For example:

> I ran that command and found the culprit, it was https://github.com/sjl/z-fish.

Answer (score 1):

Fish [has deprecated the `^` operator for stderr redirection](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/commit/a918cabf5e1c148bbdde81213016e852a21914a4); something like

```
foo ^/dev/null
```

now needs to be written this way:

```
foo 2>/dev/null
```